# Insert list of int's

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with inserting a list of int's to an object. The controller looks like:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int productID)
    {
        //ProductEditViewModel pm = new ProductEditViewModel();

        Product product = _pr.GetProducts().ByProductID(productID).First();
        product.Categories.Load();
        //ICollection<Category> allCategories = _cr.GetCategories().ToList();

        List<SelectListItem> Categories = (from category in _cr.GetCategories().ToList()
                                           join pc in product.Categories
                                           on category.CategoryID equals pc.CategoryID into j
                                           select
                                           new SelectListItem
                                           {
                                               Selected = j.Any(),
                                               Value = category.CategoryID.ToString(),
                                               Text = category.Categoryname
                                           }).ToList();

        ViewData["allCategories"] = Categories;

        return View("Edit", new ProductEditViewModel { Product = product });
    }

    //
    // POST: /Products/Edit/5

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Edit(Product product, int[] CategoryID)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add update logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

How do I update/insert all the list of CategoryID's for "product.Categories"?

And shall I have something else rather than "int[] CategoryID"?

Thanks in advance
/M

Comment: Is that LINQ to SQL you are using there? It seems to me that your question is more related to the data access technology you are using than it is to ASP.NET MVC, so may I suggest that you expand a bit on that subject and perhaps retag your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how your View looks as that is the key point.
Your view should generate HTML similar to this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="CategoryId[0]" value="123" />
<input type="hidden" name="CategoryId[1]" value="456" />
<input type="hidden" name="CategoryId[2]" value="789" />
```

Note that the index should not have holes and you will probably have othe type of input instead of *hidden*.